# How to get accuracy result of integral in matlab?

Tags: matlab, nan, integral

I don't know how to set the intevals of a integral to get the best precise result.

For example, this is the orginal definition of the formula.

```
y=integral(@(x) log2((f1(x))./(f2(x))), -inf, inf).
```

Note: `f1(x)->0` and `f2(x)->0` when `x->-inf` or `inf`, and the decreasing speeds are different.

If I use `[-inf, inf]` Matlab gives me `NaN`.

If I narrow down the inteval, Matlab gives a number. But if I increas the inteval a little bit, I get another number. So I am wondering how to deal this kind of integral calculation? How to make it as precise as possible without `NaN`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using a numeric solution f1(x)/f2(x) is nan for x=inf, maybe the symbolic toolbox can help. Is it available? How is f1 and f2 defined?

Comment: Hi Daniel:f1=@2 normpdf(x,0,1). f2=sum_{i=1}^N(normpdf(x,i,1)).

Comment: The syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your integral converges for the definitions you have given. For example, for N=1 the integrand simplifies to (1/2 - 2*x)/log(2), which is clearly nonconverging at infinity. For larger N the integrand goes to -inf for x->inf and to inf for x->-inf, and I don't think the integral converges either, though I do not have a full proof at the moment.

It is good practice to examine mathematical functions analytically before running numerical analysis. If this is not possible, then try first plotting the function itself over the relevant range to get an idea of its behavior. A good way to plot functions over many orders of magnitude is by using the [`logspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logspace.html) function for x values.

Comment: Hi Naveh, Thanks for your comment. My real integral is far more complicated than the example and I checked the integral which conveges. My question is more technical than math. So it is not about the value. It is about how to avoid NAN in common practice.

Comment: If possible, please post the full integral you are trying to compute. The more complicated it is, the more places exist where an error might manifest itself.

Comment: Like I said, you can try plotting the function over the relevant range. If your range is to infinity, try plotting first the integrand and then the numerical integral over logarithmically increasing ranges. If, as you said, increasing the integration range continually changes the integral value, this could potentially hint that your integral is nonconverging. This is where an understanding of the mathematical nature of your functions can help.